# Adjust Resize in activity for view pager not working above 21

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have view pager inside activity with four fragments and each fragment has edit text in centre and button at the bottom. But when 
the soft keyboard is coming up the button is not adjusting accordingly ,i.e.  button is not visible (it is behind the keyboard).

**My Code:**

```
main_activity.xml //activity layout


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main_screen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


first_fragment.xml //fragment_layout

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="40dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="BACK"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_degree"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_next"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size40dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontSize16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/degree"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B.Tech"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontSize20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_above="@id/degree"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:text="Degree *"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontSize16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add  this line in your manifiest.xml inside activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`

Comment: edit and post your xml

Comment: Post your xml and java code

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding above lolipop we must add below property for adjust resize functionality.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Please try this.

Comment: this should be added in activity layout or fragment layout ?